# Laravel Relations with tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My question is not that simple. 
I have three tables.

1.) Company_users (with all users data)

2.) Conversations (where is stored conversation_id)

3.) Conversation_participates (example: user_id : 190, conversation_id: 209) ( user_id: 191, conversation_id: 209)

So what I want to accomplish is: 
I want to get authorized user conversations(for example : 209,210,220)

And then I need to join the table Conversation_participates and get matching user, without getting the authorized one, for displaying matching user information from Company_users table on the active user messages page.)

How this could be done?

```
 $chats = DB::table('company_users_conversation_user')->where('company_users_conversation_user.user_id', $this->auth_user->id)
            ->leftJoin('company_users_conversations', 'company_users_conversation_user.conversation_id', '=', 'company_users_conversations.id')
            ->join('company_users_conversation_user as cucu', function($query) {
                $query->where('cucu.conversation_id', '=', 'company_users_conversations.id')
                    ->where('cucu.user_id', '!=', 'company_users_conversation_user.user_id');
            })
            ->get();
```

this is how far i got to, but it's actually not giving correct data.

Comment: Where does the `company_users_conversation_user` table fit into all of this? Can you give us a simple ERD that has all the tables you're touching?

Comment: As @amphetamachine pointed out your query doesn't seem to reflect what you've described. Wouldn't just having `users` and `conversations`, with a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between them accomplish what you need?  Participants is then simply `$conversation->users`. If there's more to your requirements you'll need to explain them.

Answer (score 0):

hope this below code will work.

```
$chats = DB::table('Company_users')           
        ->join('Conversation_participates', 'Conversation_participates.user_id', '=', 'Company_users.user_id')
        ->join('Conversations', 'Conversations.conversation_id','Conversation_participates.conversation_id')
        ->where('Company_users.user_id', $activeUserId)
        ->get();
```

`$activeUserId` can be taken from auth session.

The query is based on the three table you mentioned in question. 
we dont have any details about `company_users_conversation_user`,`company_users_conversations`